# How can I tell if a laptop's video card can be upgraded?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, upgrade, integrated-graphics

Some laptops have integrated video, while others have dedicated graphics.  Still others have dual graphics that change on demand.  Most laptops have the video components built into the design of the motherboard, but some have a separate video card that can be removed.  How can I identify if a laptop has a card that can be removed?

Comment: I see the edit and the reopen votes, but what's the likely answer going to be? Check manufacturer's site? RTFM? LMGTFY?

Comment: @karan considering the question is not too localized, and that research alone might not be a simple task for this... it is now a valid question considering there are a large number of people out there who would want to know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For information like this you generally want to look over the service manual for your laptop. which may be able to be found on the company's website, although Google will probably give you links to such information a lot quicker.  Look in any section entitled "Specifications" and it will usually tell you that, in addition to things like CPU type, maximum RAM supported, etc.  The "User's Manual" is not what you want.

You also could try typing in "(computer model number) motherboard" in an Ebay search which is likely going to easily get you pictures of the motherboard, and then you can look/read there.  Some laptops have a slot type called "MXM" which is an external graphics card slot.

There isn't a standard way to know by looking at the outside of the system, or just with the make/model information, unfortunately.  Also there isn't a reliable way to know from querying a running system, although if your only graphics adapter is an Intel GMA, then the answer is "no."

If you have a cheap/low end model laptop, or a netbook, you can be assured the answer is "no."

Comment: even if you have a "high end" laptop, more than likely you cant upgrade either.  Very few laptops are made with MXM slots, usually reserved for high end gaming laptops (and even for them its rare).